# Appending an object to a dom element in jquery

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery

What would be a way to do the following?  I know I can extract the html from the object using .html() but I would like to append the object.

```
  var $firstArticle = $('.agentPressList li:first');    
  $('ul').append($firstArticle);
```

I know the below will work perfectly fine but was looking how to use a jquery object in this manner rather than using the strings on either end of the variable.

```
  var $firstArticle = $('.agentPressList li:first');         
         $('ul').append('<li>' + $firstArticle.html() + '</li>');
```

Comment: what is el, are you using  it as a tag?

Comment: ...well, I guess you'd drop that code into a JS file, and run it. If the selectors are what you intend, it should work fine.

Comment: That would work, if both selectors match something (the second one won't match anything, there's no `<el>` tag).

Comment: I guess he is trying to append the contents of that `li` element, not the `li` itself.

Comment: I am actually trying to append the li itself to another ul.  This code does not work due to it being an jquery object. I just need the html and then to append to the 'el' which is just another ul but could be anything.

Comment: I think bfavaretto's point is that `$('el')` won't ever match, as `<el>` is not an HTML tag

Comment: And I'm confused as to what the distinction between combining the objects and appending the html are?

Comment: @jnolte you should use clone see my answer,

Comment: Hi @Sushil I tried this with no luck.  Although it seems like that is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @jnolte do you have multiple 'ul' tag? what is the problem?

Comment: I tried it before you made edits with the 'true' That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [jquery clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) if you want all same li behavior at new place. other wise use html.

```
var $firstArticle = $('.agentPressList li:first');    
  $('ul').append($firstArticle.clone(true));
```

OR

```
$('ul').html($firstArticle.html());
```

Comment: It was the (true) that was missing. This makes perfect sense. Thank you!